# Laravel - search submit is not redirecting to the next blade

Tags: laravel

In my `Laravel-5.8`, I am using the index as the search page:

```
public function index()
{
    $search = '';

    if (request('search'))
    {
        $search = request('search');

        return redirect()->route('client', [$search]);
    }
        
    return view('index', ['search' => $search]);
}

public function client($clientid)
{
    $myparam = $clientid; 
    $client = new Client();

    $res = $client->request('GET','https://example/{$myparam}', [
        'query' => ['key' => 'jkkffd091']
    ])->getBody();

    $geoLocation = json_decode($res->getContents(), true);

    return view('client', [
        'geoLocation' => $geoLocation
    ]);
}
```

Here is my `index blade`:

```html
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('index', ['search' => $search]) }}">
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label blog-sidebar-label" for="search">
      <input class="search-field" type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="client id..." value="{{ $search }}">
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have this route:

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
Route::get('client/{search}', [HomeController::class, 'client'])->name('client');
```

What I want to achieve is that when the search button for index is submitted with the clientid in the text input field, it should take the clientid as parameter and pass it to client controller. Also redirect to client blade.Then when nothing is in the text input field, it should indicate.

But it is not redirecting. How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Where is submit button?

Comment: @Droid -  <input class="search-field" type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="client id..." value="{{ $search }}">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want to submit without a submit button. Then you can submit with JS :

```html
<form id="submitForm" method="GET" action="{{ route('index', ['search' => $search]) }}">

  <div class="field">
    <label class="label blog-sidebar-label" for="search">
            <input class="search-field" type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="client id..." value="{{ $search }}">
        </label>
  </div>
</form>

<!-- JS code below -->
<script>
  document.getElementById("search").onchange = function() {myFunction()};
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("submitForm").submit();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry @Droid. It now works when I used end key. But how do I make it work if I click on <input class="search-field" type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="client id..." value="{{ $search }}">

Comment: Lets make an on-change event, you have JQuery?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I added jquery method, when you change the input field, the form will submit

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.   It highlights $(this).parents("form").submit();

Comment: I added Vanilla JavaScript, try now

Comment: I am very grateful. Thanks